# Looping through pivot table VBA to idenitfy zero values

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, pivot-table

[image]

I'm trying to find a way to loop through the pivot table above. My three row labels are "Desk", "Product Type" and "Prod ID". What I'm trying to do is identify wherever the entries in column B are equal to 0 for "Product type", highlight the "Prod ID" which are equal to 0 in column B.

My attempt so far is (I realise it's a mess, I'm not very good at VBA),

```
Sub Pivot_Table()

'
' Pivot_Table Macro
'

  Dim PvTable As PivotTable
  Dim PvField As PivotField
  Dim PvField2 As PivotField
  Dim PvItem As PivotItem
  Dim PvItemL As PivotItem
  Set PvTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
  Set PvField = PvTable.PivotFields("Product Type")
  Set PvField2 = PvTable.PivotFields("Prod ID")
  Dim lRow As Long

  With ws
    lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each PvItem In PvField.PivotItems
      If Range("B2:B" & lRow) = 0 Then
         For Each PvItemL In PvField2.PivotItems
           If Range("B2:B" & lRow) = 0 Then
             LabelRange.Interior.Color = vbYellow
           End If
         Next
      End If
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

First off for "lrow" I'm getting a run time error which I don't understand because I've used that snippet of code before. And after that I'm not sure would the loop even work?

Any help greatly appreciated!!

Comment: at the point of `With ws` ws is still an empty Variant ... I recon you missed `Set ws = ActiveSheet`

Comment: Spot on, thanks for that. Still unsure of the loop, getting a mismatch error. Not sure why the syntax: "For Each PvItem In PvField.PivotItems If Range("B2:B" & lRow) = 0 Then" isn't working?

Comment: Why are you looping through PivotItems when you don't reference the PvItem object anywhere in the loop?  Maybe you should loop through cells in the range or actually use the value of the pivot item to compare and you won't need to use lrow.

Comment: I don't entirely follow? I'm trying to identify pivot items in column A for which the corresponding value in column B is 0. That's why I'm looping through pivot items.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Range.Value property to check whether a range contains the number zero. A Range as such in VBA is an object, thus cannot be compared to a number (you have to specify what property of that Range you are comparing to zero).

```
For Each PvItem In PvField.PivotItems
    If Range("B2:B" & lRow).Value = 0 Then

       For Each PvItemL In PvField2.PivotItems
       If Range("B2:B" & lRow).Value = 0 Then

           LabelRange.Interior.Color = vbYellow

        End If
    End If

Next
```

About the lrow snippet, try removing the dot before Rows.Count.

```
With ws
    lRow = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Thanks for the object/property explanation, didn't actually know that (shows my VBA ability ha). The code itself is still giving a mismatch error though?